# Loading integer attribute in a relation always came as '0'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a `Animal` and a `AnimalType` models. A animal **belongs to** a animal type and a animal type **has many** animals.

Ok.

Animal type has a attr `sex`, of type `integer`.

When I load the list of **animal types**, for example, in the `animal_types#index`, everything is ok.

But, when I do a `animal.animal_type`, the sex **always** came as 0.

My db is MySQL and I use `ruby 1.9.3` and `rails 3.2.8`.

Any issue related to this? Am I possibly doing something wrong?

BTW, my database is correct.

Thanks in advance.

More: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/7599

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couldn't it be a lazy/eager problem?
try load your entities with `Animal.include(:animal_type).all` or something like that

Comment: I change my attr to string and the problem is gone.